# Store AD Computer Names in an Array

Tags: powershell

A fairly basic script - searches Ou in AD and exports computers - I want to store each computer into an array so I can loop through later and run some commands against the computers. Although not having much luck with the array itself - am I completely off the track here?

```
$computers = @()
$i = 0
$ou = [ADSI]"LDAP://OU=Domain Controllers,DC=test,DC=local"
foreach ($child in $ou.psbase.Children) {
    if ($child.ObjectCategory -like '*computer*') { 
        Write-Host $child.Name 
        $computers[$i] = $child.name
        }
    $i += 1
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're indexing into an empty array with `$computer[$i]`.  If you don't know how big the array should be but you know it won't be huge, change to this:

```
$computers += $child.Name
```

If you know the size then allocate the array that size like so:

```
$computers = new-object string[] $arraySize
```

Then you can index into the array up to `size - 1`.

If you don't know the size and think it will be large, use a list instead e.g.:

```
$computers = new-object system.collections.arraylist
[void]$computers.Add($child.Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a pipeline, filter the objects with `Where-Object` (alias `?`), and output the names in a `ForEach-Object` loop (alias `%`). The result is either an array of names or `$null` (when the LDAP query did not return any computer objects).

```
$ou = [ADSI]"LDAP://OU=Domain Controllers,DC=test,DC=local"
$computers = $ou.PSBase.Children |
             Where-Object { $_.ObjectCategory -like '*computer*' } |
             ForEach-Object { $_.Name }
```

If you want the result to be an empty array when no computer objects are found, wrap the command pipeline in `@()`:

```
$computers = @($ou.PSBase.Children | ...)
```